# how to increment column value by 1 and reset every 9 rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to increment column value by 1 but row number 10 reset and start with 1 like that

i have like more than 600k row

I tried call all the 600k row by php and update them but i stopped and give me some error

table sample:

```
CREATE TABLE `s1_table_play` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `play_points` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `original_points` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `play_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `table_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `play_number` int(11) DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `s1_table_play` (`id`, `player_id`, `play_points`, `original_points`, `play_type`, `created_at`, `table_id`, `play_number`) VALUES
(1, 1, '200', '0', '0', '2021-07-01 10:58:00', 67667, 1);
```

this the field "play_number" need to updated and reset every 10 rows

thanks

Comment: How do you establish first and subsequent rows? Please add table definition and sample data  suppose you want to reset after 2 rows..

Answer (score 0):

I am not really clear what your data looks like or when you want to reset but a trigger might be appropriate.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
create table t
(id int, playno int);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter  $$
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row
begin
    declare n int;
    set n = (select playno from t where id < new.id order by id desc limit 1);
    set n = coalesce(n+ 1,1);
    if n >2 then set n = 1; end if;
    set new.playno = n;
end $$
delimiter ;

insert into t(id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
select * from t; 

+------+--------+
| id   | playno |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |
|    2 |      2 |
|    3 |      1 |
|    4 |      2 |
|    5 |      1 |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```